# How to know if ext4lazyinit feature is enabled in your kernel or not?

Tags: debian, kernel, ext4

I would be formatting a newish large capacity 4 TB hdd in few hours. From what little I understand, I could just format it and it will look to be formatted.

If I format it in real-time then it would probably take a long time, 10000 rpm x 4 GB DDR3 RAM. Hence Linux came up with the concept of [ext4lazyinit](https://www.thomas-krenn.com/en/wiki/Ext4_Filesystem#Lazy_Initialization).

I'm running Debian GNU/Linux 'Stretch' and have kernel 4.9 .

```
[$] uname -a

Linux debian 4.9.0-1-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.2-2 (2017-01-12) x86_64 GNU/Linux

[$] lsb_release -a

No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 9.0 (stretch)
Release:    9.0
Codename:   stretch
```

Now, according to the wiki it says and I quote -

> If enabled and the uninit_bg feature is enabled, the inode table will
>   not be fully initialized by mke2fs. This speeds up file system
>   initialization noticeably, but it requires the kernel to finish
>   initializing the file system in the background when the file system is
>   first mounted. If the option value is omitted, it defaults to 1 to
>   enable lazy inode table zeroing. - Thomas Kenn

Now is there a way to know if the above feature is enabled in my kernel or not ?

Update -

there is a `/boot/config-4.9.0-1-amd64` . The file is 7865 lines long according to -

```
[$] cat /boot/config-4.9.0-1-amd64 | tail -n 1

  7865  CONFIG_SBITMAP=y
```

Trying to grep doesn't lead anywhere -

```
[$] cat /boot/config-4.9.0-1-amd64 | grep LAZY
```

OR even ext4 for that manner -

```
[$] cat /boot/config-4.9.0-1-amd64 | grep EXT4

  6895  CONFIG_EXT4_FS=m
  6896  CONFIG_EXT4_USE_FOR_EXT2=y
  6897  CONFIG_EXT4_FS_POSIX_ACL=y
  6898  CONFIG_EXT4_FS_SECURITY=y
  6899  CONFIG_EXT4_ENCRYPTION=y
  6900  CONFIG_EXT4_FS_ENCRYPTION=y
  6901  # CONFIG_EXT4_DEBUG is not set
```

Any ideas anybody ?

Comment: Ext4 formatting of large harddrives is much faster, it was one of the improvements of the ext4. But even with ext3 hadn't been it so long.

Comment: `lazy_itable_init` is turned on by default if the kernel you are running supports automatic background initialization of the inode table ( 2.6.37+ ).

Comment: @don_crissti while I know that, is there a command or something to check the values to see, know that's it turned on ?

Comment: @don_crissti I am not dis-believing you or anything, but there should be a way to find these things, isn't there ?

Comment: Find what ? Unless you used `mkfs` with `-E lazy_itable_init=0`  it is enabled by default. You don't have to believe me, see for yourself: [mke2fs: Enable lazy_itable_init on newer kernel by default](https://patchwork.ozlabs.org/patch/323707/) And by the way - this doesn't format faster - it just lets you use the fs while it continues formatting in the background after the 1st mount...

Answer (score 1):

Google for its kernel compilation string (or check this in the "make menuconfig" of the kernel source). It surely starts with CONFIG_EXT4_FS_ . These kernel compilation flags of your actually running kernel are can be provided in /proc/config.gz (but doing this is also a kernel compile flag, thus it may or may not be enabled on your system), or by your distribution in /boot/config-your-kernel-version (your distrib may or may not provide this).

As I can remember, it is an old (at least 5 years) feature, thus your kernel probably supports it.

Online ext4 resizement doesn't work with some highly finetuned mke4fs configurations (sorry I forgot exactly what - some of the ext4 fs flags makes it impossible).

Comment: I did try using a search-engine and I don't wanna make a custom kernel, I just want to know if there is a way to know it's enabled or not. Also thre is no /proc/config.gz on my /proc directory.

Comment: @shirish Then check in /proc/config.gz or in /boot/config-x.y.z, as I wrote.

Comment: I have updated/added new info. maybe that gives more light.

Answer (score 0):

I've been working on a bug related to this ext4 feature. So far as I can tell from the kernel source (linux 4.15.x) there is no feature called 'uninit_bg'. 
It looks like it's just baked in to the ext4 filesystem, although the key feature in question is called 'lazy_itable_init'. There's be a few changes in this code and perhaps the comments + docs need to catch up with reality.

When using `mkfs` you can add the `-E lazy_itable_init=0` option as other people has said - I don't think this attribute gets stored in the filesystem's metadata - the kernel thread for handling the lazy init is triggered or not dependent upon whether `lazy_itable_init` is set, but once all block groups on the FS have the ITABLE_ZEROED flag set then the filesystem is initialised and that's that - i.e. the method of initialisation stops being of any relevance.

Comment: `uninit_bg` is not a kernel configuration item, but a filesystem feature. See `tune2fs -l /dev/<device containing the filesystem> | grep "Filesystem features"`.